# Why am I getting Zxing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner( ) constructor error?

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, zxing

I am using Zxing.Mobile to scan a barcode in my monodroid app. I am using Xamarin. According to their documentation following line of code should work:

```
 var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
 scanner.Scan().ContinueWith(t => {   
     if (t.Result != null)
        Console.WriteLine("Scanned Barcode: " + t.Result.Text);
     });
```

But i am getting following error:

```
 The type 'Zxing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner()' does not contain a constructor that takes '0' arguments
```

Any idea why am i getting this error and how can i get rid of it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you call this in an `Activity` you can simply pass `this` as an argument. If you are calling it from somewhere else, you must pass along the `Context` which you hand the `MobileBarcodeScanner`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor needs more than `0` arguments. From [here](http://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/zxing.net.mobile):

```
//NOTE: On Android you MUST pass a Context into the Constructor!
var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
    scanner.Scan().ContinueWith(t => {   
           if (t.Result != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Scanned Barcode: " + t.Result.Text);
    });
```

Comment: YOu must pass a context into the constructor on Android. Did you do that?

Comment: No i am not passing any context into the constructor. Can you tell me how to do that in xamarin?

Comment: No, I don't know how to do that. You must have a Context-object somehwere, this you must pass into the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the Context, as mentioned above, he just didn't put the context into the constructor. Heh. Hence causing confusion.

```
var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner(this.Context);
    scanner.Scan().ContinueWith(t => {   
           if (t.Result != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Scanned Barcode: " + t.Result.Text);
    });`
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
  async void HandleBarcodeButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner(this);
        string barcode = string.Empty;
        await scanner.Scan().ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.Result != null)
                barcode = t.Result.Text;
        });           
    }
```